# How do I send a variable parameter in my Firebase REST API?

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

This should be an easy one, unless I'm missing out on something. What's the proper way of adding a variable parameter to my REST query?
Say I have an input variable lastTimestamp, which is a integer value obtained from within my code.

Is the correct way as follows?

```
https://<projectid>.firebaseio.com/news.json?orderBy="timestamp"&startAt=$lastTimestamp&limitToFirst=10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're building a URL like this in your code, how to do so depends on what "within my code" means. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Dart, on Flutter. So essentially, my input in the query above is an int object lastTimestamp. I'm wondering if I should convert it into a string first before sending it in the query, unless datatypes have an impact on the query.

Comment: 1) Don't describe your language/code please, but edit your question to show the code of how you build this URL. 2) It'd also be good to see the JSON at `/news` in your database (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).